# GUI for C++ newbie

Tags: c++, eclipse, user-interface

With few years of experience with Java I decided it's time to take the time and learn C++.  I just compiled and run my first C++ with eclipse (of course) and would like to take it one step fw - I wish to build a GUI.

Question: what GUIs are available to C++, something that is an open-source and runs on Mac and eclipse.

Comment: I would really suggest you do a bit more before doing GUI. There is a lot to learn and GUI can tend to get in the way of the basics.

Comment: I totally agree! In fact I wanted to add this line that I understand the learning C++ is not about GUI but decided to omit it because I just want to 'play' with any GUI first (compare swing with QT as suggested below). Thanks for the pointer :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some have mentioned Qt, some wxWidgets.

A quick rundown on crossplatform gui toolkits that you could try:

1. [Qt](https://www.qt.io/): Looks appropriately native on whichever platform you use it on. It has its own build system however, which doesn't always like to play nicely with others. If you want the "beginners" experience in making a GUI with Qt, I recommend [Qt Creator](https://www.qt.io/download/). It's a standalone IDE built by the developers of Qt.
2. [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/): While Qt *looks* native (it tries its best to emulate the look and feel of the OS you are running on). wxWidgets *is* native. That is, it uses the GUI elements provided by the operating system. Last I looked at wxWidgets the C++ library was falling behind as far as modern development practices go. You are possibly more likely to learn bad programming habits from this library.
3. [gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org): This is from the same guys who make the GIMP and Gnome, which as a MacOS user probably doesn't mean a lot to you. They don't try nearly as hard to fit in as wxWidgets and Qt. However, they probably have the most modern C++ library. They have done a lot of work to use modern C++ development practices. This can be helpful for a new programmer, as you are less likely to learn bad habits from them. On the downside, you'll get thrust into the land of templates and function pointers and such.

Those are the big ones with the most momentum behind them. There are countless others to also consider.

Comment: It's worth noting that Qt on Mac OS X is native, with a few compliance grey areas. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtmac-as-native.html

Comment: The document you reference outlines how it is native. It's a "native" application, that uses operating system calls for drawing routines. However, they are still Qt's widgets that are drawn.

Comment: The phrase "from the same guys who make the GIMP" sounds just as unpromising as "from the director of Plan 9 From Outer Space".

Answer (score 4):

Use Qt

http://qt.nokia.com/products/
http://qt.nokia.com/products/eclipse-integration/

Comment: I second Qt. It's probably the only C++ framework with such a complete feature set that's (relatively) easy to get rolling, with the specialized IDE that comes with the SDK... If you want to do it with eclipse, it might be more complicated, though( I haven't used the eclipse plugin).

Comment: I, too, am coming from a different language and Qt has opened the doors to C++ by providing: Easy to use development tools, excellent documentation, liberal license and a huge developer following all backed by a big company. Don't bother with Eclipse - just jump in head first with Qt Creator.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend [Qt](http://www.qt.io/download/) which is open source, has an easy-to-use API with GUI designer, and can be used on many operating systems (Windows, Mac, Linux..) and looks native on whatever it's used on.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at wxWidgets or Qt:

http://www.wxwidgets.org

http://qt.nokia.com/products/

More generally, see here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits#Based_on_C_or_C.2B.2B_.28including_bindings_to_other_languages.29

I've personally used wxWidgets and found it to be quite good, if you're after a recommendation.